# Open/Libre Office: Restricting Impress to PowerPoint-compatible content?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice

Is there a way to restrict the Open/Libre Office presentation-program Impress to just PowerPoint-compatible content?  Preferably in a way that "shadows-out" or removes non-compatible animations and trans(... whatever) between slides.

I made a presentation and saved it as a ppt-file, only to discover that several of my animations and ... had been removed/replaced - I assume because they were unsupported by PowerPoint.  Alternatively, is there a list of compatible content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to restrict the content type. You may be interested in these to options in the settings:
Load/Save -> Microsoft Office
Load/Save -> General

As far as a compatibility list, no one has made one yet - that I found.

You may find this website to be helpful: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/